# How to solve authentication in laravel 4?

Tags: php, laravel-4

When login correct username & password then show error

ErrorException

> Argument 1 passed to
>   Illuminate\Auth\EloquentUserProvider::validateCredentials() must be an
>   instance of Illuminate\Auth\UserInterface, instance of User given,
>   called in
>   E:\xampp\htdocs\laravel\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Auth\Guard.php
>   on line 316 and defined

Anybody know where problem?

Answer (score 2):

Your User model MUST implement UserInterface and its methods:

```
<?php namespace Illuminate\Auth;

interface UserInterface {

    /**
     * Get the unique identifier for the user.
     *
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getAuthIdentifier();

    /**
     * Get the password for the user.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getAuthPassword();

}
```

So it must declared as something like

```
use Illuminate\Auth\UserInterface;

class User extends Eloquent implements UserInterface {

}
```

Comment: Thanks !! @ Antonio Carlos Ribeiro

Answer (score 0):

This error might also  appear when you use a different model for users (example :member)
if it's the case you need to update Authentication Model and  Authentication Table in  app/config/auth.php with the appropriate model / database table.